# Visualize a polyhedron in R

Tags: r, rgl

I am seeking to visualize the tetrahedron with vertices at

```
(0,0,0)
(2,sqrt(2),0)
(2,0,2)
(2,-sqrt(2),0)
```

Is there a built in (or packaged) way in R to visualize this without having to draw the edges/faces manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `qmesh3d`:

```
library(rgl)

vertices <- cbind(
  c(0,0,0),
  c(2,sqrt(2),0),
  c(2,0,2),
  c(2,-sqrt(2),0)
)

# Define the faces : in case of tetrahedron, all combinations of 3 vertices
indices <- combn(1:4,m = 3)

tetrahedron <- qmesh3d(
  vertices = vertices,
  indices = indices,
  homogeneous = FALSE
)

shade3d(tetrahedron, color = "grey", alpha = 0.1)
wire3d(tetrahedron, color = "blue")
```

[image]